# By using union select for inserting values into a temp table, how to insert values in the order I assigned?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I created a temp table and inserted some values into it by using union select.

```
CREATE TABLE tempdb..#tempName (ID int IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL, Name varchar(20) NULL)

INSERT INTO #tempName(Name)
SELECT 'tommy'
UNION SELECT 'jimmy'
UNION SELECT 'adam'
UNION SELECT 'lucy'
```

Problem: I want to know how to insert the value as the order I wrote. Currently it inserted in Ascending order instead.

How I want the value to be inserted:

```
-- ID -- Name
-- 1  -- tommy
-- 2  -- jimmy
-- 3  -- adam
-- 4  -- lucy
```

The Order it inserted into the temp table:

```
-- ID -- Name
-- 1  -- adam
-- 2  -- jimmy
-- 3  -- lucy
-- 4  -- tommy
```

Comment: You cannot insert data in any particular order - a table in a relational database system doesn't *have* any order per se. If you need a specific ordering, you **must** use an `ORDER BY` clause in your `SELECT` query - that's the **only** way to get a specific ordering in any relational database

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting things in alphabetical order is because of the `union`.  It does additional processing to remove duplicates.  That is why `union all` is usually recommended.

Using `union all` will probably almost always do what you want:

```
INSERT INTO #tempName(Name)
    SELECT 'tommy'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'jimmy'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'adam'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'lucy';
```

This approach works in practice and seems to produce a consistent execution plan that will produce the records in order.  But, this behavior is not guaranteed.

Multiple `INSERT`s will definitely work.

```
INSERT INTO #tempName(Name) SELECT 'tommy';
INSERT INTO #tempName(Name) SELECT 'jimmy'
INSERT INTO #tempName(Name) SELECT 'adam'
INSERT INTO #tempName(Name) SELECT 'lucy';
```

And the `VALUES` statement will work:

```
INSERT INTO #tempName(Name)
    VALUES (('tommy'), ('jimmy'), ('adam'), ('lucy'));
```

Comment: Thank you Linoff. As you said, both union all and insert worked. However the values didn't work because the way how i created my table. I have one more question regarding to this topic. I tried to set a integer type local variable to be max(ID), and called the local variable by "ID int IDENTITY (local variable, 1) NOT NULL". I wants to know why it returned error message that local variable need to be integer type. and could I use a local variable in this way?

Comment: Sorry, I am new to sql. please be patient with me. I also wants to know what is not guaranteed by using Union ALL. Reference-->"this behavior is not guaranteed" in Union ALL. I did some research on it. But I didn't find an answer.

Comment: @baciyan . . . You cannot use a local variable as the name of a column or table.